# Javascript JQuery Script click link by code (Sliding Form Script)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using Fancy Sliding Form .. Demo [Click here](http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/FancySlidingForm/):

There are some tabs/buttons for navigation at the bottom.

I need to be able to tigger the different steps (auto clicking) when I click on a link not directly on the tab with my mouse.

I've tried adding an id to each step and then create a link: Next Tab
then the jquery below:

```
<script>
$("#mytrigger").click(function(e) {
 e.preventDefault();
 $("#step2").trigger("click");
});
</script>
```

but that didn't work.

UPDATE:

I put this together and it's not working ... I'm I not doing this right?

```
<a class="mytrigger" href="#">Click Here</a>
<script>
$('a.mytrigger').click(function(e){
$('#navigation li:nth-child(' + (parseInt(current)+1) + ') a').click();
e.preventDefault();
});
</script>
```

Here is my Nav:

```
<div id="navigation" style="display:none;">
<ul>
<li class="selected">
<a href="#">Step 1</a>
</li>
<li>
<a href="#">Step 2</a>
</li>
<li>
<a href="#">Step 3</a>
</li>
<li>
<a href="#">Step 4</a>
</li>
<li>
<a href="#">Step 5</a>
</li>
<li>
<a href="#">Step 6</a>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Use `$(document).ready(function() { ... });` and `<script type="text/javascript">`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not really able to test this, but that should work (based on the source of the plugin) :

`$('a.mytrigger').click(function(e){

    $('#navigation li:nth-child(' + (parseInt(current)+1) + ') a').click();

    e.preventDefault();

});`

The 'current' var is defined in sliding.form.js

**Edit** :
Well, I was wrong, sorry.
Here is a working demo : http://jsfiddle.net/dCmA7/1/
(full size : http://jsfiddle.net/dCmA7/1/embedded/result/)

To keep things as simple as possible, you don't have to modify the navigation.
Create your link like this :
`a href="#step1" class="mytrigger">link`

Then add this javascript :

```
$("a.mytrigger").click(function(e){  
    var index = $(this).attr("href").substr(5);  
    $('#navigation li:nth-child('+parseInt(index)+') a').click();  
    e.preventDefault();  
});
```

Comment: Could you please check the update I've posted? Seems like I might not be doing this right?

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem can be solved more easily, with less HTML. 
have a look at [my fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f2f4f/2/).

A little explanation :

1. I am creating links onload usig $(function()) method. I find all the "li" items, and I am adding "next","prev" links on them. At the end I remove the "prev" link from the first item and the "next" link from the last item. This way I don't need to constantly create HTML elements on my own.
2. Each link I add, I identify with a class "next" or "prev".
3. I bind with "[live](http://api.jquery.com/live/)" ( you might need to use "[on](http://api.jquery.com/on/)" instead . the syntax might be a bit different)

   with the "live" method I attach "click" event on each link. the handler operates on each link according to its "next"/"prev" class I attached from before. 
   For the "next" class, I use the "[next](http://api.jquery.com/next/)" function in JQuery to get the next "li" element. 
   For the "prev" class, I use the "[prev](http://api.jquery.com/prev/)" function in JQuery to get the previous "li" element.

   Please note that before I invoke "prev" or "next" functions, I make sure I reference the "li" object which is wrapping the link. For that I use the "[closest('li')](http://api.jquery.com/closest/)" call on $(this)

   Let me know if there's anything more you need.