# Reversing jQuery code function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code which when used in a link goes forward to the next link ... so I'm basically using it to do the function of a next button.

What I need to do is to create a reverse version so I can use it as a Back button.

Here is the code:

```
<script>
    $("a.mytrigger").click(function(e){  
        var index = $(this).attr("href").substr(5);  
        $('#navigation li:nth-child('+parseInt(index)+') a').click();  
        e.preventDefault();  
    });                         
</script>
```

UPDATE:

Please see the link below for further details:

[Javascript JQuery Script click link by code (Sliding Form Script)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8726871/javascript-jquery-script-click-link-by-code-sliding-form-script/8727481#8727481)

Comment: parseInt is not necessary here

Comment: can you just put a `-1` in there? `parseInt(index) - 1`

Comment: Without seeing the HTML that accompanies this, could you not just use `(parseInt(index) - 1)` to click on the previous link?

Comment: Please see this link for more details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8726871/javascript-jquery-script-click-link-by-code-sliding-form-script/8727481#8727481

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem can be solved more easily, with less HTML. 
have a look at [my fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f2f4f/2/).

A little explanation :

1. I am creating links onload usig $(function()) method. I find all the "li" items, and I am adding "next","prev" links on them. At the end I remove the "prev" link from the first item and the "next" link from the last item. This way I don't need to constantly create HTML elements on my own.
2. Each link I add, I identify with a class "next" or "prev".
3. I bind with "[live](http://api.jquery.com/live/)" ( you might need to use "[on](http://api.jquery.com/on/)" instead . the syntax might be a bit different)

   with the "live" method I attach "click" event on each link. the handler operates on each link according to its "next"/"prev" class I attached from before. 
   For the "next" class, I use the "[next](http://api.jquery.com/next/)" function in JQuery to get the next "li" element. 
   For the "prev" class, I use the "[prev](http://api.jquery.com/prev/)" function in JQuery to get the previous "li" element.

   Please note that before I invoke "prev" or "next" functions, I make sure I reference the "li" object which is wrapping the link. For that I use the "[closest('li')](http://api.jquery.com/closest/)" call on $(this)

   Let me know if there's anything more you need.